# Sphinx documentation: split a python source into sections, using autodoc

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autodoc

I'm using Sphinx with `autodoc` to document my sources.
Lets say I have a file `pre_processing.py`, containing 3 classes.
I would like to have section in the generated HTML files, like this

```
Main
====
Topic1
------
blabla
Here is included class1 and class2 doc

Topic2
------
blibli
Here is included class3 doc
```

However , all that I can manage so far is this:

```
Main
====
Topic1
------
blabla
Here is a link to  class1 and class2 doc

Topic2
------
blibli
Here is a link to class3 doc

Here is cdumped class1, class2 and class3
```

How can this be achieved please? Do I have to abandon `autodoc`, and fill my rst file manually ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, but maybe it will work as you want it if you use `autoclass` (which produces documentation for a single class) instead of `automodule`.

Comment: yes if i use autoclass, then i can edit the rst file and build my sections as i want with autoclass. But i would like to define the sections inside the python sources, somehow. Liek saying "this class belong to section x, this one to y, etc".

Answer (score 3):

You can do that, by putting your outline (and accompanying text) into the docstring of the module itself. Let’s say this is your `pre_processing.py`:

```
# yada yada license yada
"""
Main
====
Topic1
------
blabla

.. autoclass:: class1

.. autoclass:: class2

Topic2
------
blibli
Here is a link to class3 doc
"""

class class1(…):
    """
    docstring of class 1
    """

…
```

Then you can simply use `.. automodule:` in your `.rst` file:

```
.. automodule:: pre_processing
```

That will first read the docstring of the module and generate the documentation from there. Due to the autoclass directives in there, the classes are also documented.